# Smoother link between comments and chats

Tags: feature-request

I recently had StackOverflow suggest to me for the first time to move a discussion that was going on in comments to a chat. So I did, and it automatically put a link to that chat in the comments under my name.

Over a week later, the other person had not replied, and I just happened upon that question/answer. I still saw the link to that chat under my name, clicked on it, and got a 404 page.

Now, my question/request is to make this less confusing. I actually emailed team@SO about it because I thought it was a technical issue, but apparently it was just because the chat was archived after a week of inactivity. I understand that these chats may have a limited lifetime, but my issue is that it is still being linked to from that comment under that question/answer. It's as if I put a broken link there, and people reading the conversation will get confused.

I believe the simplest solution would be to explain a little more on that 404 page, and explicitly state that the chat has been archived due to inactivity. Or that it is a private chat that is not available to the public (I don't even know whether that is the case, actually). Right now it just looked like a broken link to me.

Comment: But it is still only a link in a comment in a discussion that went nowhere. Say that the chat hadn't been archived yet, people would just see an empty chat. Is that less confusing than the chat having disappeared? I'm not saying that it couldn't be made a little better, but on the other hand I don't really see a problem to be solved unless you assume plenty of people can't reason what a 404 means when it is a link to chat from a week old comment. I'd rather worry about what to do with the question that went nowhere, to be honest. Solve it at the root.

Comment: I've sometimes wished that there was a quick way to say "join me in chat" when the prompt hasn't appeared yet.  Or that there was a way to record useful discussions for future readers. When a discussion hasn't gone off topic, and is still relevant to the answer and has new discoveries, I prefer to keep using comments instead of chat, because nobody looks at old chats (esp. when the link doesn't have a summary, and esp. when the link dies!)  So the transition between comments and chat could be better, but just pointing out the details of a couple of the current mechanics isn't very interesting.

Comment: The word "move" in that message is somewhat misleading as well IMO. Because clicking on the link actually copies the messages rather than moves them. For people used to `File.Move` vs `File.Copy` this is not the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

> It's as if I put a broken link there...

It is extremely unlikely that someone is going to see a link to chat in a 7+ day old comment and assume the link was broken when it was posted. And anyone who has gone into extended discussion in comments will know it was auto-generated anyway.

> ...and people reading the conversation will get confused.

People understand that 404 errors mean the resource wasn't found. It doesn't particularly matter *why*.

> my issue is that it is still being linked to from that comment under that question/answer

You can delete the comment since it's under your name.

I know it's possible to [make comments self-destruct](https://stackapps.com/questions/6316/self-destructing-comments) so maybe you or someone else can alter that script to check whether your comment contains a dead link.

Comment: [Cool URIs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) :P

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Change, no. Become obsolete? Well, yes. Resources can be *removed* (as old chat rooms in fact are), and in that case a URN might still apply, but there is no conceivable URL that could be correct. A destroyed resource *has* no location, and can't be found.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: [Fixed URI](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI) for that site

Comment: This answer is so not helpful. If the resource is not there, why is the link still pointing to it, why confuse people? If I see such a link I rather think it has a typo then the resource is offline. And of course delete it yourself... because we don't care about it. You created the link so take the responsibility for it instead of of saying it's your problem now.

Comment: @t3chb0t It is the user's fault if that link exists. Comments are not for extended discussion. If a moderator has to move a discussion to chat, it's because it got to long.