# Deleting comment-generated chat rooms is counterproductive

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

When a conversation on a question or answer gets too long, users have the option of creating a chat room.

Sometimes, the choice will be made by moderators, cleaning up long conversations and moving them into chat.

Those conversations contain potentially useful related information for any future visitors reading the questions: I imagine a *lot* of conversations that are long enough to warrant moveing into a chat room are some sort of debugging session, in the form of "have you tried X? And Y?". You'll often find possible approaches to solving the problem there, and also the user providing more detailed information about their problem.

Often enough, it is not practical to incorporate all that information into an existing answer, or to create a new answer based on it. It just doesn't pass the bar for that. Keeping that stuff in the chat room for future visitors seems like the perfect solution!

However, those chat rooms get auto-deleted after a couple of days. ([Real world example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349728/why-would-let-us-continue-this-in-chat-404))

That seems... counterproductive. It also doesn't seem to be owed to any necessity on a technical level: the deleted chat rooms *continue to exist*, they are just only visible to 10k+ users. The link to the deleted chat room continues to exist in the comments, helpfully telling any non-10k+ users that there might be further info in a place they can't reach.

The obvious solution would seem not to automatically delete those chat rooms, but to freeze them. No?

Comment: The Dark Forces to push SO from Q+A into a forum format are ever present, ever powerful.  Personally I don't mind that much, some uncommitted noodling in a chat thread on the usual intentionally vague question makes life a wholeheckofalot easier, beats urging an asker to start adding info to the question.  Good Lord do they fight that tooth and nail lately, exhausting.

Comment: I like that Idea: let's hide information in chat rooms and not in an answer/question, for accessibility reasons.

Comment: @Tom whether comments should be moved into chat rooms in the first place is not the issue here. That's already happening, like it or not. The question is should we also delete them after a couple of days, or maybe not.

Comment: I support this, but just a small note on the 2 point there. The moving of comments by mods, is usually when the comment chain extends beyond 25 comments. In those cases, it'll not be deleted.

Comment: Btw, fwiw, on the occasion I do continue discussions in chat I've always preemptively gone back and left a comment on the post summarizing anything interesting from chat, so it's mostly been a non-issue for my own experiences, at least. Then again, I *was* a [Boy Scout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_Motto).

Comment: Let's not forget the ocassional brilliant joke comment with 50+ upvotes that gets dragged to the chatroom at then lost forever. That brilliant tiny little sample of human wit at its highest, just... lost forever... even more lost that _tears in the rain_...

Comment: @Pekka웃 Looks like you missed the point of my comment: important information don't belong into the comments (at least not for a longer period of time), thus preventing to delete chat rooms is not the correct way to handle this.

Comment: I dunno, though, no matter *how* I think about it, this entire thing boils down to people forgetting that comments are never guaranteed to stick around, and neglecting to put important info in answers. You yourself have mentioned it multiple times in the past (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338299#comment414252_338299) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204094#comment651426_204094)), but this FR confusingly seems to be centered around making certain comments essentially permanent. Can you reconcile this FR with the "comments are second-class citizens" philosophy?

Comment: @JasonC there's a difference between deleting superfluous comments, and  ones that add something of value to the post. The latter shouldn't happen, even though you have to assume it might (unfortunately). That not deleting chat rooms would immortalize a lot of stuff that shouldn't be immortalized is true... but it's arguably still out of the way, keeping the main post tidy, and what we have now is wholesale automated deletion of *everything* which most of us wouldn't agree with were it to happen to comments.

Comment: For the record, I'm not a very happy promoter of the "second class citizens" philosophy; my related feature requests are generally more an expression of resigned acceptance that the philosophy exists, and is unlikely to go away. I think there's a lot of comments that genuinely don't fit in an answer of their own, add value to the post, and shouldn't be second class citizens.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you still support [comment decay over time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140703)?

Comment: @JasonC I think it would be worth a try, *if* the decay can be stopped by comment upvotes, so the community needs to actively point out what it wants to keep around! I made a [related suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140703/let-comments-decay-by-default-add-option-to-make-them-permanent) once but it wasn't well received and probably not that good either.

Comment: @BhargavRao Do moderators have the ability to permanently delete certain chat messages in chat rooms created from comment threads? What about permanently deleting the room itself (i.e. not even visible to 10k users)?

Comment: @JasonC Yes, once we permanently delete a message, no one else can see it (Including mods). Permanent deletion of a room is also possible, which is to make the room private and then delete it. This one would not be visible to anyone, except mods (and only if they have a direct link). (if you want to test it out, create one and ping me)

Comment: @JasonC I think the reason why that's not feasible is that there's no way to distinguish between "deleted because of really evil/offensive content" and "deleted for more benign administrative reasons". At least that's why we're not letting people see deleted posts that they reach through a direct link, IIRC.

Answer (score 6):

I'm posting this as a separate answer because this isn't about supporting or objecting to the request, or numbers, but rather a question about a subtle concern that I am having trouble wrapping my head around.

Ignoring *where* the comments are and focusing only on visibility: Prior to the move-to-chat ability ([tool for mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239513/add-a-move-comments-to-chat-link-in-the-mod-menu-instead-of-only-in-the-fla/262154#262154), tool for CMs was added roughly one year prior, the actual ability was added around 2011 but it was rarely used and was a manual process done by CMs), comments could be in one of these states:

- Present (visible to all)
- Deleted (visible to mods only)
- Permanently deleted? (visible to nobody; I'm assuming CM's could nuke them)

Now, comments in chat are [still deletable by mods](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349776/deleting-comment-generated-chat-rooms-is-counterproductive/349786#comment477041_349776)<sup>1</sup>, but not as readily so (currently; my hypothesis is chat text deletions are rarely done at the moment, we did at least confirm it is [not as convenient](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37347448#37347448)), so for all intents and purposes comments in chat rooms are "semi-permanent" (or "relatively permanent", I suppose, heh). So, once move-to-chat became a common tool, comments could be:

- Present (visible to all -- these are on posts)
- Semi-permanent (visible to all -- these are in active/frozen rooms)
- Semi-permanent but hidden (visible to 10k users -- these are in deleted rooms)
- Deleted (visible to mods only)
- Permanently deleted (visible to nobody -- these are individually deleted chat messages)

And if this FR were implemented, comments could be:

- Present (visible to all -- these are on posts)
- Semi-permanent (visible to all -- these are in active/frozen/<s>deleted</s> rooms)
- Deleted (visible to mods only)
- Permanently deleted (visible to nobody -- these are individually deleted chat messages)

That is, the "semi-permanent but hidden" goes away.

Now, I can't put my finger on it, but something doesn't feel *right* about this. When you look at it this way, essentially this is making certain comments less convenient for deletion. Whether that's a bad thing or not, I really don't know, but it seems vaguely at odds with long-standing philosophies and also, more significantly, for reasons I don't understand it seems sort of XY problem-y, but I'm not really sure what the *real* issue and *real* solution could be.

I'm not saying this *isn't* right, nor am I attempting to object to the FR, I'm just... mildly uncomfortable and wondering if this is the right approach. Very open to input.

Does anybody have any thoughts on this? Why is this bothering me and is it something that matters?

---

<sup>1</sup> Just in case:

> Yes, once we permanently delete a message, no one else can see it (Including mods). Permanent deletion of a room is also possible, which is to make the room private and then delete it. This one would not be visible to anyone, except mods (and only if they have a direct link). ... – Bhargav Rao♦

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm kind of on the fence.

On one hand, you make the argument that there's no real benefit to deleting them. This makes sense.

On the other hand, there are approximately (looking at page counts on the chat index, caveat: an unknown portion of these are not related to posts):

- Active rooms: 50*20+11 = **1011**
- Frozen rooms: 3247*20+6 - 1011 = **63935**
- Deleted rooms: 7049*20+3 - 1011 - 63935 = **76037**

And of those 76037 deleted rooms, after a moderately exhaustive search, it seems that users have cared enough about a broken link to report it on meta *twice* ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333243/smoother-link-between-comments-and-chats) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349728/why-would-let-us-continue-this-in-chat-404), the latter being the post that presumably triggered this suggestion). This is a *really* low problem rate, even if you allow for the possibilities that I missed a few and that only a small fraction of users bothered to report it (even a factor of 100 or more is still a fraction of a percent). The other thing is we're generally happy to accept (and point out) the transience of comments, and this is about the same (the only difference is here you're directly aware that something was deleted, which may just be an argument for auto deleting the chat comment when the room is deleted, dunno). Plus there's a pretty straightforward solution: Raise a custom flag on the comment and ask a mod to undelete the chat.

So, on the aforementioned other hand: There doesn't seem to be much reason to *not* continue doing things the same way.

Either way I think the arguments for both sides are pretty weak, hence, the fence.

**Other Option #1:** If a solution that's more of a compromise is desired, [Smoother link between comments and chats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333243/smoother-link-between-comments-and-chats) could be implemented with a 404 page that says something along the lines of "This chat room has been deleted, if you believe this to be a mistake you may *request its undeletion*" with the last few words being a link that raises a mod flag or something.

**Other Option #2:** An alternate compromise solution could be to add "has not been *viewed* in at least X days" to the auto deletion rules. That seems to make logical sense, anyways: If people are still visiting it, it must be interesting on some level.

In any case, it's easy to look at one presumably rare instance of an issue and view it as a large problem, especially if you've directly encountered it, but it *does* seem to be rare, and does have a "workaround" of sorts for now (comment flag, or have 10k rep, of course), so, I dunno. In any case, at least there's some numbers.

---

By the way, as for comments moved by mods vs. comments moved by users, it's [somewhat rare](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345978/616460). Currently (considering only non-deleted posts and chat links), there are approximately ([query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/676686)):

```
All Time:
TotalPosts   35769436   
ModMoved         1021
UserMoved       84000     
TotalMoved      85021
FracModMoved     1.2%

Past Year:
TotalPosts    5586967            
ModMoved          410              
UserMoved       19275             
TotalMoved      19685              
FracModMoved     2.1%
```

Those numbers are roughly 20% short all around due to deleted posts (see linked post above for analysis there), so add some padding. That's included just as a data point, although it probably doesn't matter who created the chat rooms in the context of this FR.

---

Additional stats that would be useful here that only a CM could pull:

- # of flags vs. # of rooms [not] deleted in response to them, because the # of rooms not deleted upon flag request represents a user who wanted a solution but didn't get one, which is relevant. Maybe a CM can pull this, or a list of custom flag reasons and comment text on all comments that match the chat room pattern, then we can check for sure.
- I wonder if SE tracks requested URLs when serving 404's, stats about missing requested chat links for < 10k users would be relevant.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option that the rooms is deleted and the link would function as a perma-link to the transcript? So the information would still be present.

Comment: @Thaillie That's a good idea, too. Can non 10K users see transcripts of deleted rooms? (Hard to check atm on phone)

Comment: For as far as I know, no. (Tested it with the room mentioned in the question)

Comment: "users have cared enough about a broken link to report it on meta twice" Are there numbers for how many chat rooms have actually been undeleted by mods? I would not expect a Meta post to be the first thing J. Random User would try when encountering a broken link in a comment; I'd expect a comment flag, which is invisible.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Afaik there is no way for us normal people to get that but maybe somebody will pull it. The useful number there would be # of flags vs. # of rooms [not] deleted in response to them, because the # of rooms *not* deleted upon flag request represents a user who wanted a solution but didn't get one, which is relevant. For flags that led to undeletion the user got what they wanted so the FR isn't strictly necessary there. Maybe a CM can pull a list of custom flag reasons and comment text on all comments that match the chat room pattern, then we can check for sure.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I would have thought that the first thing J. Random User would try when encountering a broken link in a comment would be to give up looking for answers and just raise a new question.

Comment: A useful thing to note here is that many of the viewers aren't even Stack Exchange members. Even those that are need 5 reputation to talk on meta and 75 to raise a flag. A huge percentage of viewers then wouldn't be capable of doing anything about it. (I don't have any actual numbers, though).

Comment: In my opinion, the amount of meta questions asked is not a good metric on determining how low or high the problem rate is. I wonder how many people may have hit those 404s and decided to move on or to bring this to attention in other ways (eg flagging, or by commenting on the question itself to ask for clarification).

Comment: @g00glen00b I agree, but on the other hand (lots of other hands) even if it were off by a factor of 100, it's still a fraction of a percent. I only mentioned it because the disparity was so huge. In addition to some of the stuff mentioned in the above comments, I wonder if SE tracks requested URLs when serving 404's, stats about missing requested chat links for < 10k users would be relevant.